# I can't read JSON file in Javascript and return the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, object

I have gone through multiple posts regarding the matter but can't seem to solve the issue.
I had a method `getData()` that returned an object with a property called `results`. This property contained an array of objects as follows.

```
function getData() {
  return {
    "results": [{
        "title": "Terminator: Dark Fate",
        "poster_path": "/vqzNJRH4YyquRiWxCCOH0aXggHI.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [28,878],
        "shows": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
        "backdrop_path": "/a6cDxdwaQIFjSkXf7uskg78ZyTq.jpg",
        "overview": "More than two decades have passed since Sarah Connor prevented Judgment Day, changed the future, and re-wrote the fate of the human race. Dani Ramos is living a simple life in Mexico City with her brother and father when a highly advanced and deadly new Terminator – a Rev-9 – travels back through time to hunt and kill her. Dani's survival depends on her joining forces with two warriors: Grace, an enhanced super-soldier from the future, and a battle-hardened Sarah Connor. As the Rev-9 ruthlessly destroys everything and everyone in its path on the hunt for Dani, the three are led to a T-800 from Sarah’s past that may be their last best hope.",
        "runtime": "2h14m",
        "release_date": "2019-10-23"
    },{

        "title": "Fast & Furious Presents: Hobbs & Shaw",
        "poster_path": "/kvpNZAQow5es1tSY6XW2jAZuPPG.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [28,12,35],
        "shows": [0,3,4],
        "backdrop_path": "/qAhedRxRYWZAgZ8O8pHIl6QHdD7.jpg",
        "overview": "Ever since US Diplomatic Security Service Agent Hobbs and lawless outcast Shaw first faced off, they just have swapped smacks and bad words. But when cyber-genetically enhanced anarchist Brixton's ruthless actions threaten the future of humanity, both join forces to defeat him.",
        "runtime": "2h16m",
        "release_date": "2019-08-01"
    }]
  };

}
```

I want to migrate the same data into a `.json` file and be able to retrieve it through the property `results` and through this method itself.
The file called `data.json` I created is

```
 [{
        "title": "Terminator: ",
        "poster_path": "/vqzNJRH4YyquRiWxCCOH0aXggHI.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [28,878],
        "shows": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
        "backdrop_path": "/a6cDxdwaQIFjSkXf7uskg78ZyTq.jpg",
        "overview": "More than two decades have passed since Sarah Connor prevented Judgment Day, changed the future, and re-wrote the fate of the human race. Dani Ramos is living a simple life in Mexico City with her brother and father when a highly advanced and deadly new Terminator – a Rev-9 – travels back through time to hunt and kill her. Dani's survival depends on her joining forces with two warriors: Grace, an enhanced super-soldier from the future, and a battle-hardened Sarah Connor. As the Rev-9 ruthlessly destroys everything and everyone in its path on the hunt for Dani, the three are led to a T-800 from Sarah’s past that may be their last best hope.",
        "runtime": "2h14m",
        "release_date": "2019-10-23"
    },{

        "title": "Fast & Furious Presents: Hobbs & Shaw",
        "poster_path": "/kvpNZAQow5es1tSY6XW2jAZuPPG.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [28,12,35],
        "shows": [0,3,4],
        "backdrop_path": "/qAhedRxRYWZAgZ8O8pHIl6QHdD7.jpg",
        "overview": "Ever since US Diplomatic Security Service Agent Hobbs and lawless outcast Shaw first faced off, they just have swapped smacks and bad words. But when cyber-genetically enhanced anarchist Brixton's ruthless actions threaten the future of humanity, both join forces to defeat him.",
        "runtime": "2h16m",
        "release_date": "2019-08-01"
    }]
```

I had also included the `results` property in the `.json` file but it threw an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`

How do I retrieve the content of the `.json` file in Javascript? I tried using `XMLHttpRequest` also but no luck!
Thanks.

**EDIT**
After using XMLHttpRequest:

```
function fetchJSONFile(path, callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                if (callback) callback(data);
            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', path);
    httpRequest.send(); 
}
```

```
fetchJSONFile('data.json', function(data){
    /*
    Outputs error on console:
VM540:43 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 2617
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.httpRequest.onreadystatechange (app.js:253)
   */
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: "I had also included the results property in the .json file but it threw an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'" — It threw that when you did what?

Comment: "I tried using XMLHttpRequest also but no luck!" — What did you try? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: I basically copied from other posts I found on this form and replaced the filename. I tried using $.ajax as well. It returns undefined.

Comment: @Quentin I meant that I extracted everything after the return statement and put it in the json file.

Comment: What, exactly, is `undefined` because `$.ajax` shouldn't return that. Try including a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.

Comment: Sounds like your JSON file in invalid JSON